# How to remove suffix id added on sql server that was previously added SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have added a suffix id to allow merging of data in sql using the following query

```
Update [databasename].[dbo].[customers] set [relnum] = RTRIM(relnum) + '-9999' GO
```

It has been run more than once. I need to know how to remove it completely and also how to only leave one instance of -9999 on the field in the dbo

*relnum**

```
test-9999-9999-9999
0000109-9999-9999-9999
62077-9999-9999-9999 51387-9999-9999-9999
```

Can anyone give me an idea or ideas on how to remove it completely and also leave only one set of -9999

Comment: replace(relnum, '-9999','') + '-9999'. I.e. remove all -9999, and then add one -9999.

Comment: @jarth add this as answer its a good solution to the OP's porblem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This covers all possible scenarios. Using `CHARINDEX()` and `LEFT()` functions:

[Fiddle sampl](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81e5d/1)e

```
UPDATE Customers SET relnum = 
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-9999', relnum, 1) > 0 THEN 
                  LEFT(relnum, CHARINDEX('-9999', relnum, 1)-1)
            ELSE relnum 
        END + '-9999'
```

Data before update

```
|   relnum      |
|---------------|
| abc-9999      |
| xyz-9999-9999 |
| pqr           |
```

Data after update

```
|   relnum      |
|---------------|
| abc-9999      |
| xyz-9999      |
| pqr-9999      |
```

Comment: this worked.. Thanks a lot. How would i remove the suffix entirely??

Comment: Well, remove the last `+ '-9999'` in the update query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
Update [databasename].[dbo].[customers] set [relnum] = replace(relnum,'-9999-9999','-9999')
```

Run it a few times and you'll be fine.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE customers set [relnum] = SUBSTRING(relnum, 1, LEN(relnum) - 5)
WHERE relnum LIKE '%-9999-9999'
```

The aim is remove every time you rin this script, the last suffix -9999 from your row where exists at least two concatenated -9999 suffixes

This script you must launch several times until all -9999 you don't want, go away.

Show [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5a88/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Hope your actual column value does not contain "-9999"

```
Update [databasename].[dbo].[customers] set [relnum] = REPLACE([relnum], '-9999', '') + '-9999' where LEFT([relnum], 5) <> '-9999'
GO
```

Comment: no it doesn't its a unique number pertaining to a store and i can't disclose it